# Java and SWIG: class into a package

Tags: java, c++, namespaces, package, swig

I've followed the advice on "Swig and Java" docs:

> I'm compiling my code and I'm using templates. I provided a
>   javapackage typemap, but SWIG doesn't generate the right JNI field
>   descriptor. Use the template's renamed name as the argument to the
>   "javapackage" typemap:
>
> %typemap(javapackage)  std::vector  "your.package.here"
>
> %template(VectorOfInt) std::vector;

, but it doesn't work for me.

I have the interface file which looks like this:

```
%module moduleJava

%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_wstring.i"

%typemap( javapackage )  std::vector < double >  "Package";
%typemap( javapackage )  std::vector < std::wstring > "Package";

// Instantiate templates used by example
%template(DoubleVector) std::vector < double > ;
%template(StringVector) std::vector < std::wstring > ;

%pragma( java ) jniclasspackage = "Package"

%include java_file1.i
%include java_file2.i
```

In each of the other interface files that are included, I have objects that are in other namespaces, but all within "Package" namespace, like this:

```
//java_file1.i
%{
    #include "header.h"
%}

%nspace Package::OtherPackage::Class;

%include "header.h"
```

So every class is getting to the right place, folders are created and package indication is inserted... Except DoubleVector and StringVector - they remain unchanged in global scope and jni signatures are not matching the package.

Does the `%typemap( javapackage )  std::vector < double >  "Package"` work? Or what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give command as below for packaging your files in specific package. SWIG won't create the directory, so make sure it exists beforehand.

```
swig -java -package com.company.swig -outdir com/company/swig inteface.i
```